# My IC pins are too small

Tags: integrated-circuit, cables, pins, adapter, ribbon-cable

I bought an IC, but the little pins are too small to fit into the female end of the wire.

I do not want to use a breadboard or solder the wires.

Are there any solutions?

[image]

Comment: `Are there any solutions?` - buy a breakout board with ZIF socket.

Comment: A breadboard is probably one of the more straightforward ways of doing this for prototyping, and is worth the investment if you don't have one on hand. Can you share why you prefer not to use one, so that we can write answers that better fit your specific needs?

Comment: Depending on the IC and it's function, you might not get away with wires like that anyway. For example, digital signals with sharp edges might ring excessively.

Comment: @questioner:  Yeah.  Use a breadboard or solder the wires.  You don't want to, but those are the normal ways of connecting things.  You could also try [wire wrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_wrap), but that takes special tools and wire that you don't have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buy a wire-wrap socket and push your jumpers onto its pins.

[image]

Image from https://futurlec.com/Sockets/ICS14MTWWpr.shtml

Comment: So my IC slots into the top, and my cable fits into the pin at the bottom?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Note, that these pins are sitting in these wire sockets pretty tightly and they are pointy.

Comment: @questioner Note that you'll need a fairly small flat-blade screwdriver to get the chip out of one of those sockets: lift the IC a little bit at a time from each end to avoid damaging the IC pins.